# Naming the ArrayList Dynamically in Java

Tags: java, json, arraylist, hashmap

Suppose I have a json as

```
{
  "data": {
    "json": [

      {
        "value": [
          "john","joy"
        ],
        "key": "Names"
      },

      {
        "value": [
          "25A",
           "26B"
        ],
        "key": "john"
      },

      {
        "value": [
          "27A",
          "28B"
        ],
        "key": "joy"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to do create a Dynamic ArrayList names for each values as shown below

```
for(String name:Names){
  //create a dynamic arraylist from the names here like 
 // ArrayList<String> joy= ..........
}
```

Can Anyone help me with this please?

Comment: why down vote ? without commenting anything? Feel pity on some people.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put("arrayname", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: will try this. Thanks

Comment: I want the name to be the `name:Names` and the number of list will also be the numbers of name ..